# flutter 'crumb' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: flutter, dart

I installed the flutter But I want to run it in CMD, I get this error:

```
'crumb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

All addresses are correct
Prerequisites installed
```

Comment: So... what command did you actually run?

Comment: I just wrote "flutter"

Comment: hey, were you able to solve it?